# Secondary axis line graph ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I managed to create the following chart in ggplot2

[image: plolt]

by using the following code:

```
                                         "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
                                         "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
                                         "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), Year = c(2008, 
                                                                                                2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
                                                                                                2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 
                                                                                                2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
                                                                                                2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021), Value = c(13, 
                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 23, 1, 0, 24, 5, 2, 19, 13, 4, 3, 27, 10, 0, 14, 34, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                           4, 44, 0, 2, 49, 0, 1, 53, 0, 1, 55, 0, 1, 57, 0, 1, 57, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                           57, 0, 1, 57), Share = c(64.3873493612449, 64.3873493612449, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    64.3873493612449, 60.3873493612449, 60.3873493612449, 60.3873493612449, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    52.1568314927171, 52.1568314927171, 52.1568314927171, 47.1706943758496, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    47.1706943758496, 47.1706943758496, 42.1444027058278, 42.1444027058278, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    42.1444027058278, 37.1718223783312, 37.1718223783312, 37.1718223783312, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    32.4750630408817, 32.4750630408817, 32.4750630408817, 28.3433373848839, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    28.3433373848839, 28.3433373848839, 24.5584081133868, 24.5584081133868, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    24.5584081133868, 21.1966663593617, 21.1966663593617, 21.1966663593617, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    18.1282210145941, 18.1282210145941, 18.1282210145941, 16.6527237518679, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    16.6527237518679, 16.6527237518679, 14.2045390727677, 14.2045390727677, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    14.2045390727677, 12.3492805575519, 12.3492805575519, 12.3492805575519
                                                                                                                                                           )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -42L))

# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)

# stacked area chart
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Value, fill=`Category`)) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.5)

p <- p + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
              panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray95"), 
              panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray20", fill=NA, size=0.5))

# customized plot
p <- p+geom_area(colour = NA, alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_line(position = "stack", size = .1, color = "gray25") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2021, by = 1),
  expand = c(0,.1)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 60, by = 5), expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Category") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom') + theme(text=element_text(size=14,  family="serif"))

# add second axis and line
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name = 'Share (%)'))
p <- p + theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 10)))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = `Share`/1, linetype = "Share", color="Share"), size=0.8, linetype = "solid") 
p
```

Now I would like to make two changes, which I couldn't figure out yet:

1. Remove the term "colour" in the legend and make the gray box around the line disappear
2. Add points only to the red line "share". I tried using `geom_point` but it added points to every line on the chart

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @Neicooo, could you please share again your data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fist part: Just add two lines at the end: `+ labs(color="")` (removes the term colour in the legend), `+ theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))` (changes background around the line to white).

```
p <- p + labs(color="") +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
p
```

For the second part: specify the `aes()` within geom_point to only plot points along the red line:

```
p + geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=Share), color = "red")
```

However, this gives you points in the `geom_area` legend too. To overwrite this:

```
p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
p
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to first remove the term `colour` in the legend and second give the red line of share `points`:

```
# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)

# stacked area chart
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Value, fill=`Category`)) + 
  geom_area(alpha = 0.5) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray95"), 
               panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray20", fill=NA, size=0.5))

# customized plot
p <- p+geom_area(colour = NA, alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_line(position = "stack", size = .1, color = "gray25") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2021, by = 1),
                     expand = c(0,.1)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 60, by = 5), expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Category") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom') + theme(text=element_text(size=14,  family="serif"))

# add second axis and line
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name = 'Share (%)'))
p <- p + theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 10)))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = `Share`/1, linetype = "Share", color="Share"), size=0.8, linetype = "solid") + geom_point(aes(x=Year,y=Share)) + labs(color = "") + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) 
p
```

Output:

[image]